# The invoice don't change to paid

Tags: odoo

I'm using odoo 8 
I can create Invoices, and Validate.
I can register a payment, but, even if i register a payment with the value of the invoice.
The invoice don't change to paid.

Comment: What is the state of your payment.

Comment: The state is still open

Comment: You need to validate your payment if you want it to be considered in your invoice

Comment: Thank you , I already click on paying but the state remains open while in the menu payment provider . The state is already posted screen shoot > [screenshot1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B331hDPNiShtR0tkVFlfLVBCekE)  ,[screenshot2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B331hDPNiShtUnBUcXVxM0VoeW8)

Comment: Does your payment appear among the payments of the invoice? You can also check at the "Provider payments" menu to see the state of your payment

Comment: What does the Balance say on your invoice? It's not on the screenshots :/